# Is it possible to store each return of the same http request in an array in jmeter?

Tags: javascript, java, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jsr223

In my post processor I have the following code:

```
if (i as Integer < protocolsArray.length){


          
protocolsArray[i as Integer] = "${requestProtocolId}" ;

}
```

and it worked, I put the "requestProtocolId" that I got via JsonExtractor in the position of "i", position of i == 0

but the number of virtual users defined in this http request is greater than one.

so it sends the request again and saves the new "requestProtocolId" again in position zero, overwriting the other protocol,I understand that with the new request it starts all over again, taking the initial values ​​assigned to the variables again, but I've already tried incrementing the i (i ++) and returning the new array with the zero position filled in:

```
vars.putObject("protocolsArray", protocolsArray);
```

but it always returns the value set before the htpp request, is there a way to change that?

If I changed and put an iteration controller and it was a group of users but in iteration controller "5", it would be like the same user would send it five times, right?

I wanted to simulate different users, but always keep the "requestProtocolId" value saved in the array positions because I'm going to use it in another request.

Answer (score 0):

In its current state your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

- [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are [local to the thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) (virtual user)
- If the user starts new iteration - the variable will be still there, if this is not something you want/expect - use [vars.remove()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#remove-java.lang.String-) function to ensure that the variable is always "fresh"
- Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables in scripts, in case of [Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#remove-java.lang.String-) (the recommended scripting option) only first occurrence will be cached and used during other iterations, see [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation for more information

Comment: I managed to solve my problem in another way, I no longer needed to save to an array, I just passed the Thread group along with the variable I got in JsonExtractor, in BeanSheall Assertion,
and in the next Thread Group, in the http request I call this variable along with its ThreadGroup in the url, it no longer repeats the requestProtocolId, it runs once for each Thread I passed, using the requestProtocolId that was generated by the Thread.